# Slick slider item is not centered on mobile device

Tags: javascript, vue.js, slick.js

[image]

On a mobile device, the items are displaying like this. However, I want the first item to be centered. What is the problem?

Slick code:

```
slickOptions() {
    return {
       rows: 0,
       infinite: true,
       slidesToShow: 4,
       slidesToScroll: 4,
       responsive: [
           {
             breakpoint: 1301,
             variableWidth: true,
             settings: {
               slidesToShow: 4,
               slidesToScroll: 4,
               },
             },
             {
               breakpoint: 641,
               variableWidth: true,
               settings: {
                 slidesToShow: 1,
                 slidesToScroll: 1,
                 initialSlide: 1
               },
            },
         ],
     };
},
```

I have tried using `initialSlide`, but that's not working.

I have also tried adding the CSS: `transform: transform3d(0, 0, 0);`, but that also failed to fix the problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to use `variableWidth: true`, you may have better luck adding `centerMode: true`. This should ensure that your current slide is centered in the slideshow.

Additionally, your `variableWidth` value should be set in the `settings` object. Note, you only need this setting if your slides are actually different widths.

```
  slickOptions() {
    return {
       rows: 0,
       infinite: true,
       slidesToShow: 4,
       slidesToScroll: 4,
       responsive: [
           {
             breakpoint: 1301,
             settings: {
               slidesToShow: 4,
               slidesToScroll: 4,
               variableWidth: true,
               centerMode: true
               },
             },
             {
               breakpoint: 641,
               settings: {
                 slidesToShow: 1,
                 slidesToScroll: 1,
                 initialSlide: 1,
                 variableWidth: true,
                 centerMode: true
               },
            },
         ],
     };
  },
```

Comment: Still it's not working. My sliders are the same width.